# Google Sheets to output variable to Discord

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, discord, urlfetch

I am attempting to create a script that outputs a cell in the same row to discord based on a checkbox. I've written up so far the following, although I'm really not very good with javascript/Google Script. I cannot get past the auth requirements and do not see the mistake I am making.

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

function onEdit(e) {

var discordUrl = "Webhook";
var userName = 3
var channelMsg = userName

  let checkboxColumnNo = 5
  let range = e.range;
  let value = range.getValue().toString();
  let column = range.getColumn();
  let row = range.getRow(); 
  let sheetName = range.getSheet().getName()
  
  if (column == checkboxColumnNo && value === "true") {userName;
  }
  var payload = JSON.stringify({content: "Whitelist add " + channelMsg });
  var params = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'}, method: "POST",payload: payload,muteHttpExceptions: true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(payload);
  Logger.log(channelMsg);;
}
```

[image]
Just showing what my sheet layout looks like.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It looks that this question requires more an expert on making https requests to the the Discord API rather than on using Google Sheets / Apps Script, so I will migrate it to [so].

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your code with something very similar that I've done I can only spot 1 difference which is the following:

Your code:

```
  var params = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'}, method: "POST",payload: payload,muteHttpExceptions: true};
```

My code:

```
    var params = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
};
```

Difference:

In your header you have this which I don't, try removing it to see if it works.

```
'Accept': 'application/json'
```

Little bonus, here's a tool I use to make nice embedded messages for Discord:
https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/

Comment: I removed it, i had to modify some parts of it after i posted this. im trying to get it to send the answer via webhook command to auto-whitelist upon checkbox. 
It outputs the response to the correct channel, but for the userName var it only puts "Range" so i end up with 'Whitelist add Range' instead of the username.

Comment: If you're only getting range you're probably selecting the cell correctly, but forgetting to add the `getValue()` function add the end.

Comment: i had to redefine my variable.
var userName = sheet.getRangeByName("ign").getValue();

now the only issue is it grabs the top most value in the range, doesnt grab the corresponding one

Comment: edit, i forgot that i can use an Else parameter on an If statement. i feel dumb, i fixed the issue of it pulling the wrong variable and used the else statement to undo the whitelist.